# Why into Minkowski metric we use a pseudo-Riemannian metric and not, simply, a pseudo-metric?

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, tensor-products, bilinear-form

> A pseudo-Riemannian “metric” is a nondegenerate quadratic form on a real vector space $R^n$
>
> A pseudometric space $(X,d)$ is a set $X$ together with a non-negative real-valued function $d\colon X \times X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ (called a '''pseudometric''')
>
> A bilinear form is simply a linear map $\langle -,-\rangle\colon V \otimes V \to k$ out of a tensor product of k-modules into the ring k (typically taken to be a field).

Minkowski metric is described as a pseudo-Euclidean metric, but not only is it not positive definite, it defines a pseudonorm which takes negative values.

When we talk of a (pseudo-)Riemannian metric, we are not simply talking of the (pseudo-)metric on a vector space. We are talking of a (pseudo-)metric field. The (pseudo-)metric is a property of the tangent space at a point on the manifold; a (pseudo-) metric is strictly a field, that is it is function from the points on the manifold to the tangent (tensor) space at each point.

1. For metric space we don't need that space should be a real *vector* space, it can be just a *set* with a a non-negative real-valued function that respect 3 rules (symmetry, subadditivity/triangle inequality)
2. nondegenerate quadratic form arise a requirement for a vector space, not exist  for a pseudo-metric space

Question: why use a complicated pseudo-Riemannian space solution that include a bilinear form instead of a very more simply, pseudo-metric metric idea ?

Why use a twisted pseudo-Riemannian contortionism into Minkowski metric?

Comment: Because ... that is what the Nature seems to be like. The Minkowski metric on flat $4$-dimensional vector space (Special theory of relativity) or on $4$-dimensional manifolds (General theory of relativity) is the best way to express the laws of Nature (with respect to space, time, electrodynamics at large scale and gravity) that humankind has come up with so far. Good luck to anyone who would want to improve on that.

Comment: As you already observed yourself, the term “metric” does *not* mean the same thing in “pseudo-metric space” and “pseudo-Riemannian metric”. If the second concept were instead called a “semi-Riemannian form” would it have even occurred to you to ask why we use that concept instead of a pseudo-metric? Note also that the topology defined by a pseudo-metric is not Hausdorff while a pseudo-Riemannian manifold is Hausdorff. Also, the  *nondegeneracy* of a pseudo-Riemannian metric in each tangent space is an essential aspect and you propose no way to get these with a pseudo-metric.

Comment: A topology defined by a pseudo-metric is T1 space? Because Hausdorff is T2. Mm..maybe our attention should be not focused on nondegeneracy in each tangent space, but the fact that both spaces include [pre-topological spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretopological_space) ? I don't think that is needed to replicate same pseudo-Riemannian aspects in a way to get them with a pseudo-metric because I am interested in limiting them to what they are in common, eliminating what they will be: 2 different spaces.